# I need to detect which is the ACTIVE (as opposed to installed) PDF viewer in Firefox 19

Tags: firefox, pdf, adobe, acrobat

I have an issue where I need to know whether or not my customers who use Firefox 19 have the Adobe PDF plugin set as the browser's default viewer (and not the new embedded viewer). javascript can detect if it is installed, but that is not enough.

So far the only solution I've come across is to detect Firefox 19 and then open a popup that warns users that they *may* need to manually change their PDF viewer to Adobe. I'd really rather not have to do that.

Has anyone had any luck getting more detailed PDF info from FF19?

Answer (score 2):

What if we do this:

```
if(document.contentType="text\html" && window.location.href.endsWith(".pdf") > -1)
        return true; // native PDF viewer is opened
else
        return false;
```

Above Snippet is based on assumption that for a PDF file the URL will always end with .pdf.